# Need help LOOPING function

Tags: vba, excel

i have problem with my code... look like this

```
Worksheets("Daily Consump").Cells(67, OutputNumber).Value = (CDbl(Kiln.Cells(25, OutputNumber + 3).Value) - CDbl(Kiln.Cells(25, OutputNumber + 2).Value)) * CDbl(Kiln.Cells(25, 4).Value)
Worksheets("Daily Consump").Cells(68, OutputNumber).Value = (CDbl(Kiln.Cells(26, OutputNumber + 3).Value) - CDbl(Kiln.Cells(26, OutputNumber + 2).Value)) * CDbl(Kiln.Cells(26, 4).Value)
Worksheets("Daily Consump").Cells(69, OutputNumber).Value = (CDbl(Kiln.Cells(27, OutputNumber + 3).Value) - CDbl(Kiln.Cells(27, OutputNumber + 2).Value)) * CDbl(Kiln.Cells(27, 4).Value)
Worksheets("Daily Consump").Cells(70, OutputNumber).Value = (CDbl(Kiln.Cells(28, OutputNumber + 3).Value) - CDbl(Kiln.Cells(28, OutputNumber + 2).Value)) * CDbl(Kiln.Cells(28, 4).Value)
Worksheets("Daily Consump").Cells(71, OutputNumber).Value = (CDbl(Kiln.Cells(29, OutputNumber + 3).Value) - CDbl(Kiln.Cells(29, OutputNumber + 2).Value)) * CDbl(Kiln.Cells(29, 4).Value)
Worksheets("Daily Consump").Cells(72, OutputNumber).Value = (CDbl(Kiln.Cells(30, OutputNumber + 3).Value) - CDbl(Kiln.Cells(30, OutputNumber + 2).Value)) * CDbl(Kiln.Cells(30, 4).Value)
Worksheets("Daily Consump").Cells(73, OutputNumber).Value = (CDbl(Kiln.Cells(31, OutputNumber + 3).Value) - CDbl(Kiln.Cells(31, OutputNumber + 2).Value)) * CDbl(Kiln.Cells(31, 4).Value)
```

i think my code not good, do you any suggest to make it in simple code, maybe using looping, but i have any fail in that:
here my trial

```
'For k = 25 To 31
'    For j = 67 To 73
'        Worksheets("Daily Consump").Cells(j, OutputNumber).Value = (CDbl(Kiln.Cells(k, OutputNumber + 3).Value) - CDbl(Kiln.Cells(k, OutputNumber + 2).Value)) * CDbl(Kiln.Cells(k, 4).Value)
'    Next j
'Next k
```

please advise me how to do that

Comment: What is the fail? What is the error message, or the unexpected result?

Comment: there is no error, but i want to just make my code simple, with looping, can you do that?

Comment: You can do this without VBA, using Array Formulas in Excel cells directly. It will be fast, and obvious what Excel is doing. Lookup Excel Array Formulas for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest instead of VBA to do this directly in Excel sheets. Here is an example of how to make the formulas:

[image: Formula]

The result cells take the difference between columns Value A and Value B and multiply by the numbers on column Scale. To enter the formula you need to press `CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER` while the result cells are selected (as seen above). The result is seen below:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

```
With Kiln
    For k = 25 To 31
        Worksheets("Daily Consump").Cells(k + 42, OutputNumber).value = (CDbl(.Cells(k, OutputNumber + 3).value) - CDbl(.Cells(k, OutputNumber + 2).value)) * CDbl(.Cells(k, 4).value)
    Next k
End With
```

Comment: thanks alot.. it works.... just need a another vision.. hahaha... only change j with k, why my brain was frozen... thanks alot dude...